# Biblatex footnotestyle with second name, brackets and the title

Tags: biblatex

The footnotes generated with biblatex are not perfect.

Now:
[image: Footnote Now]

Better:

> ¹Vgl. MUSTERMANN, Hans (1994): The World Wide Web

The minimal example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,titlepage]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[babel,german=quotes]{csquotes}

\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\bibliography{literaturdatenbank}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{ngerman}{
    references = {Q},
    urlseen = {URLSEEN is},
    url = {Online}
}

% Config for Bibliography list:
\DeclareFieldFormat{urldate}{\bibstring{urlseen}\space#1}% Remove the () im Datum
\DeclareFieldFormat{url}{\bibstring{url}\space\url{#1}\addcomma}
\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamelast}[1]{\textsc{#1}}
\renewcommand*{\labelnamepunct}{\addcolon\space}


% Interne Literaturdatenbank normalerweise auszulagern
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{literaturdatenbank.bib}
@online{ art:web,
  author = {Hans Mustermann},
  title = {The World Wide Web},
  year = {1994},
  url = {http://www.pageisdown.tld/subpage.html},
  urldate = {2013-02-01}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage[toctextentriesindented]{tocstyle}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\section{Text}
Text\footcite[Vgl.][]{art:web}.
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: Do you want this more verbose style for all entry types and all successive citations?

Comment: @moewe: No, I mean that the first `\footcite[Vgl.][]{art:web}` give the same result why the second \footcite[Vgl.][]{art:web}`. In the footnote list then two elements with the same content. But with different nummbers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the following definitions:

1. Declare the name format for citations:

   ```
   \DeclareNameAlias{labelname}{last-first}
   ```
2. Define a new cite-macro:

   ```
   \newbibmacro*{cite:footnote}{%
     \iffieldundef{shorthand}
       {\ifthenelse{\ifnameundef{labelname}\OR\iffieldundef{labelyear}}
          {\usebibmacro{cite:label}%
           \setunit{\addspace}}
          {\printnames{labelname}%
           \setunit{\nameyeardelim}}%
           \printtext[parens]{\usebibmacro{cite:labelyear+extrayear}}%
           \setunit{\addcolon\space}%
           \usebibmacro{cite:label}%
       }
       {\usebibmacro{cite:shorthand}}}
   ```
3. The final dot inside the citation is done by `\bibfootnotewrapper`. So you can change the default definition to:

   ```
   \renewcommand{\bibfootnotewrapper}[1]{\bibsentence#1}
   ```
4. Redefine the initial `\footcite` command

   ```
   \DeclareCiteCommand{\footcite}[\mkbibfootnote]
     {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
     {\DeclareNameAlias{labelname}{last-first}%
      \usebibmacro{citeindex}%
      \usebibmacro{cite:footnote}}
     {\multicitedelim}
     {\usebibmacro{postnote}}
   ```

---

Here a complete MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,titlepage]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[babel,german=quotes]{csquotes}

\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\bibliography{literaturdatenbank}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{ngerman}{
    references = {Q},
    urlseen = {URLSEEN is},
    url = {Online}
}

% Config for Bibliography list:
\DeclareFieldFormat{urldate}{\bibstring{urlseen}\space#1}% Remove the () im Datum
\DeclareFieldFormat{url}{\bibstring{url}\space\url{#1}\addcomma}
\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamelast}[1]{\textsc{#1}}
\renewcommand*{\labelnamepunct}{\addcolon\space}

\renewcommand{\bibfootnotewrapper}[1]{%
  \bibsentence#1}
\DeclareCiteCommand{\footcite}[\mkbibfootnote]
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\DeclareNameAlias{labelname}{last-first}%
   \usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{cite:footnote}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\newbibmacro*{cite:footnote}{%
  \iffieldundef{shorthand}
    {\ifthenelse{\ifnameundef{labelname}\OR\iffieldundef{labelyear}}
       {\usebibmacro{cite:label}%
        \setunit{\addspace}}
       {\printnames{labelname}%
        \setunit{\nameyeardelim}}%
        \printtext[parens]{\usebibmacro{cite:labelyear+extrayear}}%
        \setunit{\addcolon\space}%
        \usebibmacro{cite:label}%
    }%
    {\usebibmacro{cite:shorthand}}}

% Interne Literaturdatenbank normalerweise auszulagern
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{literaturdatenbank.bib}
@online{ art:web,
  author = {Hans Mustermann},
  title = {The World Wide Web},
  year = {1994},
  url = {http://www.pageisdown.tld/subpage.html},
  urldate = {2013-02-01}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage[toctextentriesindented]{tocstyle}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true]{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\section{Text}
Text\footcite[Vgl.][]{art:web}.
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

> [image]

Comment: It works better. How can I remove the dot at the and of the footnote.

Comment: I mean something other.
At the end of the site, in the footer.
`Vgl. MUSTERMANN, Hans (1994): The World Wide Web.` This dot.

Comment: @user5361: I fixed it.